# Getting environment variables

Tags: environment-variables

The `env` command does not give all the environment variables on Ubuntu 12.04, like those used by individual applications.

How could I get all environment variables?

Comment: Try `( set -o posix ; set ) | less`.

Comment: Then you are actually talking about shell variables, not environment variables. @Videonauth showed how you can view them. Suggested reading: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson I posted it only as a comment because I wasn't really sure what the OP now really wants.

Comment: Like others said, perhaps you want the shell variables which are superset of env variables..

Comment: `env` *does* print the values of all current environment variables. Can you clarify what you're asking for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well while I'm not really sure if this is what you want, you can get all the shell variables with the following commands:

```
set -o posix
set
```

Or if you want it in an easily scrollable way you can pipe it through `less` like the following:

```
( set -o posix ; set ) | less
```

This will provide, like [@heemayl](https://askubuntu.com/users/216503/heemayl) stated in his comment, all shell variables of which `env` is a subset .

As [@Gunnar Hjalmarsson](https://askubuntu.com/users/159370/gunnar-hjalmarsson) stated, you can find out [more about environment variables here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables).

Answer (score 1):

While Vedeonauth's answer is completely valid for the current process, it sounds like you're asking for all of the installed applications.  So to get the environment of all *running* applications do:

```
sudo find /proc -name environ -maxdepth 2 | xargs cat | xargs --null --max-args=1
```

(Thanks to [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/66366/205542) for the part at the end which turns the null-delimited `environ` files into something human-readable.)